# Linkify inconsistency

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, linkify

I have a list with photos like Instagram, with text that has links to hashtags and users using `#` and `@` and I'm using Linkify to make this work.

The **1st item** in my list gets the links correct 8/10 times but the other times its just plain text. The other items always get their links correct.

**BaseAdapter**

```
// holder is a ViewHolder class holding my row views
// holder.photo is a ParseFile subclass object 
// holder.photo.hashtags is an arraylist with objects
// holder.photo.comment() is a getString("key") from ParseObject
// hashtags is a String with hashtags, for example "#hashtag #anotherhashtag"

holder.hashtag.setText(hashtags, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
holder.title.setText(holder.photo.comment(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
StringUtils.linkify(activity, holder.photo.hashtags, new TextView[]{ holder.hashtag, holder.title });
```

**StringUtils**

```
public static void linkify(Activity activity, List<Hashtag> hashtags, TextView[] textViews ) {
    for (TextView t : textViews) {

        // currently only using hashtags
        Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

        // Linkify url
        String newActivityURL = "app://";

        // Add links
        Linkify.addLinks(t, tagMatcher, newActivityURL);

        // Get spannable
        Spannable spannable = (Spannable) t.getText();
        URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);

        // Replace text with span
        for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            int start = spannable.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = spannable.getSpanEnd(span);
            spannable.removeSpan(span);

            // Hashtag is a ParseObject subclass
            Hashtag selectedHashtag = null;
                for (Hashtag h : hashtags) {
                    // Fix url for clickable link
                    String URL = span.getURL().replace("app://" + "#", "");
                    if (URL.equals(h.getObjectId())) {
                        selectedHashtag = h;
                    }
                }

                if (selectedHashtag != null) {
                    span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(a, selectedHashtag, selectedHashtag.name());
                    spannable.setSpan(span, start, end, 10);
                }
            }
        }
```

#### URLSpanNoUnderline

```
class URLSpanNoUnderline extends HashtagSpan {

    private Activity a;

    public URLSpanNoUnderline(Activity a, Hashtag h, String p_Url) {
        super(p_Url, h);
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashtagActivity.hashtag = hashtag;
        // Start activity
    }


    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint p_DrawState) {
        super.updateDrawState(p_DrawState);
        p_DrawState.setUnderlineText(false);
        p_DrawState.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in `holder.hashtag.setText(hashtags, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)` a bit? I wasn't aware that `setText` was able to to take in an ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry, `hashtags` is a normal string containing all hashtags (simple arraylist loop with `hashtags = hashtags + ", " + newHashtag` flow.

Comment: Could you post some examples that work and don't work

Comment: It's not necessary. The hashtag/user either shows up as a hashtag/user or normal untouched text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

The problem came from all threads not finishing simulatenously. I had one task where it would get information about my picture and one that would get the hashtags (from relation to actual object) that were attached to the photo.

**Solution was to make sure all info was loaded into the adapter when the last object in my for-loop was added to the list of objects** making sure there were no objects added/changed after the adapter had been updated.